# Query For Parts of a File Path

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my MySQL database that stores a file path.  I'm trying to figure out a query that will return the next folder in the file path given a string (or the root dir, given no string).  So say I have the following:

```
/this/is/my/folder
/this/is/another/folder
/folder/one
```

My query would return 'this' and 'folder'.  Or if I gave it the string '/this/is/', it would return 'my' and 'another'.  This may not be possible in the same query, so I can just add code logic if I need two queries.

I believe I can do this with regex in mysql but I wasn't sure if there was another way to do this in mysql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to extract the portions you require:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           Folder,
           @querystring,
           1 + CHAR_LENGTH(@querystring) - CHAR_LENGTH(
             REPLACE(@querystring, '/', '')
           )
         ),
         '/',
         -1
       )
FROM   mytable
WHERE  Folder LIKE CONCAT(@querystring, '%');
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e1b0/1).